# change format y axis to percentage in R

Tags: r

I would like to change the format of the y axis to percentage while my data is in the form of decimal numbers.

This is what I tried

```
par(mar = c(7,3, 1, 2), xpd = TRUE)

plot(my_data_cumulative$Date, my_data_sub$Compensation, type = "l", lwd = 3, ylim = c(-0.06, 0.1), lty = 1, col = "green", xlab = "", ylab = "Cumulative Change")

lines(my_data_cumulative$Date, my_data_sub$Depreciation, type = "l", lty = 2, col = "grey40",  lwd = 3)
lines(my_data_cumulative$Date, my_data_sub$Taxes, type = "l", lty = 3, col = "grey60",  lwd = 3)
lines(my_data_cumulative$Date, my_data_sub$Interest, type = "l", lty = 4, col = "grey80",  lwd = 3)
lines(my_data_cumulative$Date, my_data_sub$Corpotaxes, type = "l", lty = 5, col = "black",  lwd = 3)
lines(my_data_cumulative$Date, my_data_sub$Profits, type = "l", lty = 2, col = "blue",  lwd = 3)
legend("bottom", 
       legend = c("Compensation", "Depreciation", "Taxes", "Interest", "Corpotaxes", "Profits"), 
       inset = c(0.8,-0.5),
       xpd = TRUE,
       col = c("green", "grey40", "grey60", "grey80", "black", "blue"),
       lty = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2),
       ncol = 3,
       lwd = 3,
       cex =1)
axis(side = 2, at = pretty(ylim), labels = percent(pretty(ylim)))
```

Comment: I would like to use plot. The packages loaded are: scales, lubridate, tydiverse and readxl

Comment: You need to disable the drawing of the y axis during your first `plot` call. Perhaps add the argument `yaxt = 'n'` to this call. If you want your y axis values to be in percentages, then it is important that the values you are plotting are between 0 and 1. You haven't included a [mre], so we can't confirm this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could multiply by 100 (or do anything that scales your data appropriately to percentage) and `paste` `"%"` to it.

```
> ylim <- range(dat)
> par(mar=c(5, 5, 2, 2)+.1)
> matplot(dat, type='l', yaxt='n', xlab='foo', ylab='percent', ylim=0:1)
> axis(side=2, at=pretty(ylim), labels=paste0(pretty(ylim*100), '%'), las=2)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(matrix(runif(30), 10, 3))
```